# How to integrate aria2 or wget with google chromium?

Tags: chromium, wget

As the title tells everything, can anyone tell me the way to integrate aria2 or wget with chromium.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a project with wget integration to chromium

https://code.google.com/p/wget-plugin-chrome/